# Jquery return most recent date from table column

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm trying to use this function to get the most recent date value from my table.

```
function getdate() {
  var index = $('#csvtext table').find('th:contains("DATE")').index();
  var max = 0;

  $('#csvtext table tr td:eq(' + index + ')').each(function() {
    $this = parseInt( $(this).text() );
    if ($this > max) 
      max = $this
  });
  return max;
}
```

Table:

```
<tbody>
<tr><td>1</td><td>17/10/2017</td><td>CA5533</td></tr>
<tr><td>2</td><td>15/10/2017</td><td>CA5533</td></tr>
</tbody>
```

The problem is that `max` is returning only the first value from the date inside my column `DATE`.

How can I return the value of most recent date from all values inside this column?

Thanks!

Comment: what your table looks like?

Comment: @Vineesh, edited the code. Nisal, I saw this post and I cannot use the code for that case.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can convert your date in `DD/MM/YYYY` format to `MM/DD/YYYY` and then compare it using `getTime()` and then return the result.

```js
function getdate() {
  let maxDate = '01/01/1970';
  
  $('table tr td:nth-child(2)').each(function(){
    var date = $(this).text().replace(/(..)\/(..)\/(...)/, '$2/$1/$3');
    if(new Date(maxDate).getTime() < new Date(date).getTime()){
      maxDate = date;
    }
  });
  
  return maxDate.replace(/(..)\/(..)\/(....)/, '$2/$1/$3');
}
console.log(getdate());
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table>
  <tbody>
  <tr><td>1</td><td>17/10/2017</td><td>CA5533</td></tr>
  <tr><td>2</td><td>15/10/2017</td><td>CA5533</td></tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

Comment: Working on Chrome. Any idea about how can I use this on Firefox too? Thanks!

Comment: Firefox Error: maxDate.replace is not a function

Comment: Updated the solution. Please check now.

Comment: @HassanImam You don't need need to use `getTime()`. You can compare dates directly `new Date(maxDate) < new Date(date)`

Answer (score 0):

(I don't have rights to comment on your post.please comment on my post.your question isn't clear but I could understand your explanation.)

**Here is the modified logic for your desired output:**

(Hint: You have to iterate the rows/tr and need to get the column/td inside loop..)

```
 <!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script>
function getdate() {

          var index = 1;

          var max = null;
          $('table tr').each(function() {

             var date =  $(this).find('td:eq(' + index +')').html().split('/') ;

               var $this= new Date(date[2], date[1], date[0]);
               console.log($this);
               alert($this);
               if ($this > max) max = $this
            });
            return max;

}

$(document).ready(function(){
   var value=getdate();
   alert(value);
});
</script>
</head>
<body>

<table>
<tbody>
<tr><td>1</td><td>17/10/2017</td><td>CA5533</td></tr>
<tr><td>2</td><td>15/10/2017</td><td>CA5533</td></tr>
</tbody>
</table>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Hi! Same return here

Comment: Need to convert to date. `parseInt()` only returns first 2 digits

Comment: thanks for the reply.is 17/10/2017 is your date format?

Comment: Yeah! This function returns all values inside `DATE` column.